# Is there any on server unzip lib for PHP?

Tags: php, unzip

We are using dUnzip2 in our script to unzip files before download, write license then use zip.lib to zip it and serve.  But the dUnzip2 is using:

```
foreach ($f as $file_row => $file)
```

which works fine for small files , but for files larger than 10 mb it should use something like

```
for($n = 1;$n < count($f);$n++){
    $file = $f[$n];
}
```

which is causing memory limit issues on files that are bigger than 10MB. We have to increase memory limit on the server for that lib all the time. The script itself is HUGE and to be honest I would not dare on taking the task to modify it.

So do you know any other unzip library that would do the same job as dUnzip2 or better solution?

Comment: Just use the built-in ZIP library?  http://php.net/zip

Comment: What has your web searching turned up? I should think there are a number of unzipping libraries for PHP.

Comment: The two code examples have the same memory characteristics if one assumes that `$file_row` and `$n` take neglible memory. The former variant is actually a good practice. Note that the latter ignores the first entry in the zip file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use PHP's built in Zip stuff: http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Obviously assuming it's enabled (usually is) do a phpinfo() to check.